# iTunes prompts for password while paymentQueue is empty

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm observing some strange things with iTunes and in-app purchases, both at iOS 6 (iPad 3) and iOS 7 (iPad 4).

I have in-app purchases system in my app. Restore purchases function is implemented.

I log out from iTunes (in Settings) and make app fresh install. Then I press "Restore purchases" and enter email & password for some valid sandbox account with many (>10) purchases done previously. But, while restoring process being performed, I kill an app. Then I go to Settings and log out again.

Now it's adventures time!
When I launch app again, it asks me for password for previously logged in user. Well, OK, I enter it, and everything is fine. Then I can close & restart app again, everything will be OK.

But, after that, I log out again and restart an app... and I see an iTunes prompt for password (for previously logged user, again). Debugging my app in Xcode, I check `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions]` array... and it's empty! Also, `SKPaymentQueue`'s delegate don't receive `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:`signal.

How is it possible? For now, I am not even able to clear everything somehow - after re-installing the app iTunes prompts for password again.

Comment: It seems that storeKit has enormous bugs in sandbox mode.
I also getting this issue, reinstalling app, removing provisioning profile not solves it.
I hope this problem will not appear in production, at least people assure me in that)